# Counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL?

---

Example:

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test."user"
(
  uid integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  result integer,
  CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
```

I want to write a query so that the `result` contains column how many occurrences of the substring `o` the column `name` contains. For instance, if in one row, `name` is `hello world`, the column `result` should contain `2`, since there are two `o` in the string `hello world`.

In other words, I'm trying to write a query that would take as input:

[image]

and update the `result` column:

[image]

---

I am aware of the function [`regexp_matches`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) and its `g` option, which indicates that the full (`g` = global) string needs to be scanned for the presence of all occurrences of the substring).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM regexp_matches('hello world', 'o', 'g');
```

returns

```
{o}
{o}
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM regexp_matches('hello world', 'o', 'g');
```

returns

```
2
```

But I don't see how to write an `UPDATE` query that would update the `result` column in such a way that it would contain how many occurrences of the substring o the column `name` contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL count number of times substring occurs in text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757194/postgresql-count-number-of-times-substring-occurs-in-text)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A common solution is based on this logic: *replace the search string with an empty string and divide the difference between old and new length by the length of the search string*

```
(CHAR_LENGTH(name) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(name, 'substring', ''))) 
/ CHAR_LENGTH('substring')
```

Hence:

```
UPDATE test."user"
SET result = 
    (CHAR_LENGTH(name) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(name, 'o', ''))) 
    / CHAR_LENGTH('o');
```

Comment: This is a solid answer, and it's right. You may be interested on my write up [all the methods of doing this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166763/2639)

Comment: Thanks! Does anyone know, why there is no simpler way? I mean, REPLACE already goes through the trouble of scanning the whole string for all the occurrences, why not have something that does half of the work of REPLACE - just count the occurrences

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk: Well, you can write your own User Defined Function doing this calculation, e.g. there's Oracle's `REGEXP_COUNT` in https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.5/eeguide/EDB_Postgres_Enterprise_Guide.1.041.html.

Answer (score 74):

A Postgres'y way of doing this converts the string to an array and counts the length of the array (and then subtracts 1):

```
select array_length(string_to_array(name, 'o'), 1) - 1
```

Note that this works with longer substrings as well.

Hence:

```
update test."user"
    set result = array_length(string_to_array(name, 'o'), 1) - 1;
```

Comment: If someone needs regexp, this solution with "regexp_split_to_array" instead of "string_to_array" works too.

Comment: This solution is substantially slower than @dnoeth's suggestion. I don't think it's more-Postgres-y. When things are faster and more portable in a different method, I think we call that *better*. =)

Comment: @EvanCarroll Unfortunately, dnoeth's answer won't work for regex matches, since you may not know the length of the match. This answer will work for both regex matches and raw string matches. I think what we call _better_ is the solution that works for everything you are trying to do  :)

Comment: upvoted but i don't see what's "postgres'y" about it; let's not borrow pythonic characterizations :)

Comment: @user2297550 . . . Most databases don't support arrays natively.

Answer (score 12):

Other way:

```
UPDATE test."user" SET result = length(regexp_replace(name, '[^o]', '', 'g'));
```

Comment: This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 9):

Return count of character,

```
 SELECT (LENGTH('1.1.1.1') - LENGTH(REPLACE('1.1.1.1','.',''))) AS count
--RETURN COUNT OF CHARACTER '.'
```

Comment: This was the most readable solution for me.

Comment: This works fine for just one character, but the division is needed in the accepted answer for substrings longer than one character

Answer (score 7):

```
Occcurence_Count = LENGTH(REPLACE(string_to_search,string_to_find,'~'))-LENGTH(REPLACE(string_to_search,string_to_find,''))
```

This solution is a bit cleaner than many that I have seen, especially with no divisor.
You can turn this into a function or use within a Select.
No variables required.
I use tilde as a replacement character, but any character that is not in the dataset will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT array_length(string_to_array('a long name here', 'o'),1)
```

- 1 is for 1-dimension array
- 'o' is the occurrence you want to count