# How to separate and count string from TEXT column PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field in the Client table called "Attachment Name" which has the names of every attachment that a client has, the way the names are saved are the following, it alwas starts with a “^” character, then the name of the file, when you have to save another file the same character is placed.
So for example, in client number 1423 we have `"^file1^userGuide^file3"`, in this case we have 3 files, File1, userGuide and File3.
What i need is a way to know the clients that have only ONE file attached, or the ones that have more than one file.

I know this is an awfull way to store file names, but i did not do it this way and its not my call to change it.

I have been working with this sentence:

```
Select regexp_split_to_array("attachment_name", E'\\^+') from clients
```

But i could not make it work at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376410/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following counts the number of attachments that appear in the list:

```
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array(attachment_name, '[\^]')) as attachment, count(*)
from clients
group by attachment;
```

EDIT:

I answered the wrong question.

If you want only one attachment, then something like this:

```
select count(*)
from clients c
where attachment_name not like '^%^%'
```

Comment: You already give a simpler answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36376584/3470178)

Comment: Thank you!, that solved it, i could not use the function regexp_split_to_array because the servers PostgreSql version was old (8.2). That simple query worked fine.