# postgres: how to count text values (e.g. "yes") in a column

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I would like to count how many yes exist in each row at column B.

[image]

Any efficient way of dealing this? 
I am actually aggregating data so I am not considering creating a new table using "string_to_array".

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What data type is the column `B`? And why are you storing comma separated values in a single column? You should normalize your data model before you proceed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376410/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-in-postgresql)