# How can I get the count of susbstring matches from a SQLite cell?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a SQLite cell with the text "Row row row your boat," and I want to get the count of a certain word, i.e. "row" = 3, how would I construct that query?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36376548/500276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common method in SQL for doing this uses `length()`:

```
select length(replace(lower(col), 'row', 'rowx')) - length(col)
```