# Counting the number of occurrences of a set of different substrings within a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a database with lots of textual information, and I would like to count the number of times certain terms occur in a given text field. I know how to do this in Python, but as I am planning on documenting this spatially I'm looking for a way to store this analysis in a view on the postgres server.

There are great resources out there to do this on a single, repeating string (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta?cb=1; [Counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376410/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-in-postgresql#)). The problem is, those methods rely on proxy ways of counting this, e.g. by subtracting the length of the substring and returning the difference, divided by the length of the substring. With multiple substrings at different lengths, those approaches break.

So, if I'm interested in negative terms for the sentence "The meadows are eroded. The pasture is prone to flooding. The fields yield little", I might want to count up the occurrences of 'erode', 'prone to' and 'yield little', in this case 3.

As I might end up with quite a few of these kinds of terms, I'm looking to avoid repeating this for every substring, using the method suggested for single substrings in the first link which is:

```
length(str) - length(*replace(str, replaceStr))
  / length(replaceStr)
```

Highly appreciate the input.

Comment: And would 'prone tom'  also count as match for your pattern 'prone to'? You need to define matches carefully or live with surprising results.

Answer (score 1):

This would count how often one of these terms appears in a column:

```
SELECT id, col,
       cardinality(
          regexp_split_to_array(
             col,
             '(erode|prone to|yield little)'
          )
       ) - 1
FROM atable;
```

**Explanation:** `regexp_split_to_array` cuts the string in pieces using the pattern as separator and returns the result as array, `cardinality` counts the number of elements in an array.

Comment: Very smart. `regexp_split_to_array() might still end up costing more than a couple of lowly `replace()` etc. as regexp functions are expensive.

Comment: @gislipals What do you mean? That would depend on the input string.