# Determining the length of a comma separated string

Tags: string, postgresql, delimiter, string-length

Suppose I have a column that has a value of a comma separated string of various lengths:

```
 locations            |  city  |  county |  state
 ---------------------+--------+---------+--------
 A, B, C              |        |         |     
 ---------------------+--------+---------+--------     
 A, B                 |        |         |
 ---------------------+--------+---------+--------
 A, B, C              |        |         |
```

So, the length varies. I want to know what the length of the values separated by comma would be. For example, 'A, B, C' has a lenght of 3, 'A, B' has a length of 2. How do I find that length using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376410/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string into array:

```sql
select cardinality(string_to_array('a,b,c', ','));

 cardinality
-------------
           3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes; this was what I was looking for! The cardinality is what I forgot.